# Seeing the SQL that LINQ generates

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a LINQ to SQL statement for example

```
var query = (from a in this.Context.Apples select a.Name).ToList();
```

When I want to see what SQL is being generated by `LINQ`, what I do is that I comment out the `ToList()` and put a breakpoint on the command after this `LINQ` statement and then I can hover it and read the SQL.

My question: Is that a correct way of getting the generated SQL?

Comment: I prefer using LinqPad. It has a "SQL" tab to show the generated SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's a correct way, but of course, there are others:

```
var context = new DataClasses1DataContext();

var sb = new StringWriter();
context.Log = sb;

var query = (from a in context.Persons select a.Name);

string s = query.ToString();
string command = context.GetCommand(query).CommandText;

//The log requires the query to actually hit the database
query.ToList();
string log = sb.ToString();
```

And also Linqpad:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also set the Log property of Your context to :

```
public class MyContext : DbContext{

  MyContext(){
        Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
        //or like this 
        //Database.Log = message => Trace.TraceInformation(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use SQL Server Profiler, add a trace, and see generated queries as they are being executed by the server.